How could the USA government be sued for a rejected visa? Who should be even sued?
Imagine that a visa applicant believes, his application was illegally refused.
Who could he sue? The USA government is a federal entity, where could he even start it?
Without a visa, he could not even enter the USA, how could he be personally there in the courtroom?

Why would you need to be there in the courtroom?  You could hire local council that would bring the lawsuit.  There would generally be no reason that you would need to appear in court.  Unless you mean to ask how you could sue the government pro se which would almost certainly be a terrible idea.

@JustinCave I was not ever in this case, anyways I could enter USA any time to waste my money. I am just curious, how could this procedure ever happen without local presence.

Not at all
A state is sovereign and can only be sued when they allow it. Further, visas are purely discretionary on the state allowing you entry. Since the US does not wish to be sued for visas and they are discretionary anyway, there is no cause or way to sue for one.
There also is no appeals process to a visa denial.

Yes but the state has laws to determine, who is allowed to get a visa, and the embassy executes these laws, to quality visa applications. If they violate these laws, they can be likely sued.

@GraySheep you can't sue, because the rules for visa applications do not offer a cause of action.

@Trish, could the superior of the visa official (or an internal affairs department, if there is one) take action against the individual who made the mistake for failing to do the job properly?

@o.m. In thoroy, yes, but there is no formal process to make such a claim.  However, the person responsible for the visa is a consular officer, so pretty high up the chain

@Trish adjudicating visa applications is an entry-level function in the consular service, so the officers making those decisions are at the bottom of the chain. Moreover there are some limited circumstances in which a visa denial may be challenged in court. Also, the legal doctrine preventing most visa decisions from being heard in court is not sovereign immunity (consider e.g. the writ of mandamus). The critical principle here is known as "consular non-reviewability." In short, this answer sounds plausible, but it is incorrect in several significant respects.

@phoog OP said "sue the US", which you just can't do.

OP asked "who could he sue?"

This answer ignores Kleindienst v. Mandel, Kerry v. Din, Department of State et al v.. Munoz and the exceptions to the consular non-reviewability doctrine. Given that the premise of the question is an illegal refusal (that is, a refusal that doesn't even follow the US's own rules for refusing a visa), not grappling with the exceptions makes this answer lacking.

@Trish while this is not one of the circumstances in which the US has waived its sovereign immunity against civil suit, there are several.  More relevant, however, is the similar question "how could the US government be sued for a rejected passport application?"  While it may be strictly correct to say "it cannot," the answer is so misleading as to be incorrect for all practical purposes.  More generally, if a questioner asks about suing the wrong party, a useful answer should identify the right party, not simply say "you can't do that "

@Jen can you add an answer?  I am aware of these exceptions, but I am not familiar enough with them to write an answer without doing more research than I have time for at the moment.

@phoog I will come to this in a few days if no one else gets to it first.

@Jen is there really such a thing as an "illegal refusal" though? Afaik (at least for the USA) consular officers reviewing visa applications are specifically instructed to presume that the applicant has an intent to immigrate or at least overstay illegally, and it's the applicant's responsibility to overcome that presumption by providing convincing evidence. I don't believe that there is an official standard for what constitutes convincing evidence though, so in the end it really is up to the consular officer's discretion. There is ultimately no right to be issued a visa.

@GraySheep I think you'll find that any laws regarding visas describe the conditions under which a visa may be issued, and typically do not say that a visa must be issued if an applicant fulfills some set of criteria.
